modal popup is not able to click on button-java selenium
The pop-up appears after 6-7 sec  but not able to click on the join button or enter a text can anyone send a code for this?
https://www.guru99.com/learn-sap-testing-create-your-first-sap-test-case.html
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15));
WebElement modalWindow = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("cb-box__inner-bg")));

// Check if the modal window is displayed
if (modalWindow.isDisplayed()) {
    System.out.println("Modal window is displayed.");
    WebElement closeButton = modalWindow.findElement(By.className("cb-form-group__btn.ff-inherit")); // Correct class name
    closeButton.click();

    // Wait for the modal window to close
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("cb-box__inner-bg"))); 
    System.out.println("Modal window is closed.");} 
else {
    System.out.println("Modal window is not displayed.");
}

// Close the WebDriver session
driver.quit();


no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".cb\-form\-group__btn\.ff\-inherit"}

Reason you are getting this exception is due to below line. I can't find any element matching the class name cb-form-group__btn.ff-inherit.
WebElement closeButton = modalWindow.findElement(By.className("cb-form-group__btn.ff-inherit"));

Refer the full working code below:
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(300));
WebElement modalWindow = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("cb-box__inner-bg")));

// Check if the modal window is displayed
if (modalWindow.isDisplayed()) {
    System.out.println("Modal window is displayed.");
    WebElement closeButton = modalWindow.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='cb-close'])[1]"));
    closeButton.click();

    // Wait for the modal window to close
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("cb-box__inner-bg"))); 
    System.out.println("Modal window is closed.");} 
else {
    System.out.println("Modal window is not displayed.");
}

// Close the WebDriver session
driver.quit();


The xpath for join now button was wrong i replaced it with xpath of join now //button[@type='submit']//span
